# Getting params while using DefaultMenuItem in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, menu

I am using PrimeFaces `DefaultMenuItem` with a `setParam()` but I do not get any params in my XHTML page?

```
item = new DefaultMenuItem("Active");
item.setUrl("/rem40/eventListEdit.xhtml");
item.setParam("listType","active");
item.setIcon("ui-icon-home");
eventsSubmenu.addElement(item);
```

My XHTML page has a `onpageLoad`

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewAction action="#{eventListEditModel.onPageLoad}" />
</f:metadata>
```

and in my method I use the following to retrieve the params

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String,String> params = fc.getExternalContext).getRequestParameterMap();
```

The params list is zero items.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I assume you checked the network traffic in the browser console?

Comment: no, what exactly am I looking for?

Comment: You are doing web development and are trying to access request parameters but have no clue how to find it in q browser developer tool ans what it should look like?

Comment: What is the scope of your bean

Comment: the scope is session, there is no request parms on the html link that is passed through.